# Determining licensing in CaGel by means of substitution test

Tags: syntactic-analysis, modifiers, complements

I read a comment on licensing in another post, which made me revisit this concept. Unfortunately I haven't got access to CaGEL – only to its "little brother", Huddleston and Pullum's *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* (henceforth referred to as H&P), so this is what I will refer to in the following.

In their discussion of licensing (e.g. pp65ff), H&P repeatedly use a test where they substitute the head of a VP with another verb, in order to illustrate the difference between complement and adjunct. For instance, they show on p65 that the NP *the cheese* in *Sue used the cheese* is a complement (Od) because if the head of the VP (*used*) is substituted with an intransitive verb – i.e. a verb that doesn't license a complement – we get an ungrammatical result: * *Sue disappeared the cheese*. On p71 they do the same thing with *the manager*, in *Ed told the manager*, showing that *the manager* is a complement since it is inadmissible with the intransitive verb *arrive* – * *Ed arrived the manager*.

To me, this MO seems odd, seeing that it suggests that a certain **form** always has the same **function**, regardless of the context in which it is used – something that obviously doesn't hold true. The unreliability of the substitution test becomes blatantly obvious if we use it on a clause such as *She stayed in her bedroom*, where we want to determine whether *in her bedroom* is a complement or not. If we use this test here, and substitute the head of the VP (*stayed*) with the intransitive verb *disappeared*, we get *She disappeared in her bedroom*, which is a perfectly well formed sentence. According to the test, then, *in her bedroom* should be an adjunct; however, according to H&P (p142) *in her bedroom* is, in fact, a **complement** in the VP *stayed in her bedroom*.

So, my question now is quite simply: have I missed something here? Is there a way the substitution test is, in fact, reliable as a way of determining licensing and, thereby, whether a certain element is an adjunct or a complement?

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

(for a related question, please see [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/486980/what-is-the-nature-of-and-syntactic-distinction-between-modifier-and-complemen))

Comment: You are wrong about "last week". It is a complement because in "The meeting was last week", it is an obligatory item since its omission renders the sentence ungrammatical. Both SIEG and CGEL make this very clear in the various discussions about complements and adjuncts.

Comment: If *the meeting was last week* is part of a particular longer sentence, then *last week* could be dropped, keeping it grammatical. (For instance: *I didn't know where the meeting was last week.*) It's also conceivable that *the meeting was*, entirely on its own, could be considered grammatical in the same sense that *the world was, is, and will be* is grammatical. If *was* is taken to mean *existed*. But most people parsing just *the meeting was* would not consider it to be meaningful. Also, the existence of *last week* would change the interpretation of what *was* is anyway.

Comment: But it's not part of a longer sentence, so it's a pointless argument. We can't say *"the meeting was"; that's why "last week" is an obligatory item and hence a complement. Do you actually know what a complement is?

Comment: Note that obligatory items are always complements: they are needed to complete the verb phrase; optional items may be complements or adjuncts.

Comment: @BillJ YES!! That is precisely my point! That "last week" in "the meeting was last week" is a complement. This is exactly why the discussion of licensing doesn't quite make sense to me, since it hinges on the assumption that a certain form has the same function regardless of context. See?

Comment: @Hannah It´s probably best to think of the substitution test as a test that will sometimes give you evidence that something is NOT an adjunct. However, passing the test does not guarantee that something IS a complement. Think of their being a warm-blooded test for being a mammal. If it´s cold blooded it´s not a mammal. However, if it´s warm-blooded it doesn´t tell you that it is a mammal. If something *fails* the subsitution test, it gives you strong evidence that it´s a comlement. However, passing it, for various reasons, will not guarantee adjuncthood.

Comment: "That is precisely my point! That "last week" in "the meeting was last week" is a complement. This is exactly why the discussion of licensing doesn't quite make sense to me, since it hinges on the assumption that a certain form has the same function regardless of context. See?" <--- I don´t follow you here.

Comment: H&P are not saying that a noun phrase *the manager* is always a complement. They are saying that in the sentence *Ed told the manager*, that th NP is a complement. However, they would say that in *Ed, the manager, didn´t take any prisoners*, the phrase *the manager* was a modifier.

Comment: @Araucaria, in answer to your last comment: I know – and that's why this "test" was confusing me since it rests on the assumption that we *can* change the context (i.e. replace the verb with a different verb) and still retain the same function, right? Do you see what I mean now? Still, it's not a problem any longer, because I've realised they only mean it as a test for whether sth is an *object* not as a test for whether sth is a *complement*, and as such it obviously works :) Kind of in line with your first comment to me above. Also *thank you* for your many patient answers to my questions :)

Answer (score 3):

More of a comment than a real answer but I'm not able to comment on here just yet. It seems to me this test works relatively well if you bear in mind that in:

*She stayed in her bedroom*

You can't drop *in her bedroom* without changing the meaning of the verb, whereas in

*She disappeared in her bedroom*

you can.

In the second sentence *in her bedroom*  just adds detail about the circumstances of the disappearing, whereas in the first it is integral to the meaning of the verb.

If you change the second sentence to *she disappeared into her bedroom*, you make the last bit a complement again, but now the meaning of *disappeared* is different - almost opposite, if you consider that if someone is said to have disappeared, it usually means we don't know where to find them.

In answer to your comments Hannah:

I haven't got the book you mention, but the way I understand the substitution test is that if the result is not grammatical in the original sense of the verb, that counts as a failure. Therefore, if the new sentence is not obviously ungrammatical, the omission test is used to check whether the verb is being used in a different sense - but if it is, that means that the substitution has changed the meaning, and hence that the substitution test is failed.

Maybe the omission test is more of an intuition pump than anything else, and maybe we have different intuitions about the meaning of *stayed*, but to me, it has the sense of *we're having Jack and Caitlin to stay* when used by itself. If you use it with something that's obviously an adjunct, you seem to end up with this sense - if you said *she stayed a long time*, I would take that to mean that she didn't leave the party until late, or stayed with friends or at a hotel - somewhere away from home - for a long time. There is an idea of being hosted or put up that's not there in *she stayed in her bedroom*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Im not sure whether you mean that the substitution test works well though, or if you're referring to the omission test that you illustrate? Also, I honestly don't see how *stayed* changes meaning in any relevant way if we take away the complement?

Comment: Also, I've come to realise that the substitution test probably isn't meant as a test for complements in general, but rather for objects only – if that is the case, it explains a lot :)

Comment: @Hannah *Stay* in "*having friends to stay*" means something like sleep and carry out ones domestic bits and bobs somewhere. In contrast *stay* in *I want you to stay calm/in your room/where you are*  means to not change your state or location etc. It´s meaning is close to *remain*. Notice that if the meaning changes, so do the grammatical constraints and also the grammatical functions of the phrases following *stay*. This means that sentences with the same superficial surface form may be ambiguous. I think Minty makes some good points.

Comment: @Hannah The subsitution test is no good if the verb can be used either transitively  and if the phrase concerned can also freely function as an adjunct as well as a complement of that same verb. So for example a substitution test for *every day* used with the verb *record* is no good, because a sentence such as *I record every day*  is ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you again Minty – I only just saw your addition to your answer! I can completely follow your reasoning now – thing is, this is not the way H&P reason at all; they're talking about actually replacing one verb with a completely different one, and they're not discussing omission at all, so that's why I didn't at first quite get what you meant :) It's interesting what you write about the meaning of *stay*; to me, the default meaning is 'remain in the same place', and the sense you're talking about would have to be elicited from context... So I agree about intuitions :) Thanks again!